# Plotting coordinates in map component using confidential/sensitive data?

Tags: asp.net

I'm working on a simple webform that will plot some coordinates on a map. The issue is that the data is very sensitive so I have to make certain that the points being plotted are not being stored in any 3rd-party server. I also cannot afford paying $10K for Google Maps Business.

What options do I have?

I've downloaded several good examples ([this one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36151/Show-Your-Data-on-Google-Map-using-C-and-JavaScrip) for example), but I've confirmed that the data posted can possibly be stored by google.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What distance would a point have to be from your sensitive coordinates before it was sufficiently far away that the location of the sensitive coordinates would not be compromised or revealed?  A mile? 5 miles? 10 miles? 50 miles? 100 yards? The suggestions I would give you could be very different depending upon whether your're tracking places to pan for gold, drill for oil or natural gas, or set up a coffee shop.

Comment: My boss could be setting up a hot dog stand, but if he wants those coordinates private, then private they shall remain.

In terms of distance, I really don't know. I just have the Lon & Lat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Google Maps, you will post your coordinates to their server. There's no way to prevent that. So I believe you have no choice but to host your own, or find a cheaper maps provider you want to trust with the data.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

I posted to a Google Maps forum and they confirmed that. Their least-expensive solution is $10k.